# What is the easiest way to send a tweet when a row is updated in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: twitter, google-apps-script, automation, google-sheets

So, I have a digital tap list for a bar and I'm using Google Spreadsheets as a back end for the data. When a keg runs out I want for the bar staff to be able to copy and paste the oncoming beer over the row of cells corresponding to the keg that just ran out. What would be the best way to automate a tweet when this happens? So when they change the keg, and once they update the spreadsheet that a tweet is automatically sent out saying what new beer has been put on tap.

Comment: You need to monitor for an event, then run some code that will use `UrlFetchApp`.  A Google sheet has both simple and complex triggers, that will monitor edit and change events, and run some code.  The tweet will probably need to be invoked with a GET request, which is done with [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Answer (score 1):

As far as connecting to twitter, which uses OAuth, from Apps Script, you'll need to:

- reference the sample OAuth1 apps script library. [This github repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1) has the info on how to reference that library, along with sample code for reference.
- wire up to Twitter. That repo also has a sample showing [integration with Twitter](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1/blob/master/samples/Twitter.gs).

The other code you'll need in Apps Script should implement onEdit(e), to handle the [edit event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). You'll have to do some work to inspect the range to make sure the edit is one you care about.